# Haskell lazy unloading

Tags: haskell, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I need to have a large list of data that when referenced at a specific location calculates (loads from a file, and/or generates it if it hasn't been generated yet) and keeps it for future use. This is powered by lazy lists bound to a function. These "chunks" sometimes are loaded but never really used after that while still effectively referenced in code so the GC doesn't pick up on them.

Since the RAM quickly fills up, I'd like to lazily unload these chunks after a period of time where they aren't used by anything. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "lazy unloading"? Not unloading until the last possible moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this by using `unsafeInterleaveIO` to read the chunks and periodically going through the list and removing the references to chunks that were not used for a long time (alternatively: use weak pointers as **@nponeccop** suggests in the comments), but I'd go with something that doesn't rely on GC for managing memory for the chunks (since predictable memory usage is important for you).

For example:

```
import Data.HashTable.IO

type ChunkMap = BasicHashTable ChunkId (Maybe Chunk)

newChunkMap :: IO ChunkMap
getChunk :: ChunkMap -> IO Chunk
freeUnusedChunks :: ChunkMap -> IO ()
```

where `getChunk` allocates the memory for missing chunks with `malloc` and `freeUnusedChunks` goes through the table and `free`s unused chunks.

You can even run `freeUnusedChunks` in a separate thread:

```
freeThread = forever $ do
                 withChunkMapLock $ do
                     freeUnusedChunks map
                     threadDelay 5000000
```

Comment: How might I know which ones aren't used?

Comment: Associate a timestamp with each chunk and update it on each access. Then you can either keep the last N timestamps in a circular buffer or calculate them in `freeUnusedChunks`.

Comment: What about weak pointers (`System.Mem.Weak` from `base`)? Are they appropriate here?

Comment: @nponeccop Well, one can certainly use a hash table filled with weak pointers. That will be more usable than what I suggested if one is caching Haskell values. The downside is of course that one delegates the replacement policy to the GC which might be sub-optimal.